# Jenkins add user issue

Tags: linux, jenkins, command-line, devops

When installing Jenkins I added the command 'sudo adduser jenkins' to my script and after it was completed I tried to run the command sudo su - jenkins to login as Jenkins user but it fails to work. It takes me back to [ec2-user@jenkins ~]$. What can I do?

I ran the Adduser linux command and it still doesn't work.